# Python multiprocessing within a class method

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I'm attempting to run Python methods using multiprocessing as:

```
from pylab import *
import multiprocessing

class surface(multiprocessing.Process):             
    def __init__(self,fE,fH,pm):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.fE = fE
        self.fH =fH
        self.pm = pm
    def run(self):
        self.meshx = [x for x in self.fE["Mesh/x"]]
        self.meshy = [y for y in self.fE["Mesh/y"]]
        self.meshz = [z for z in self.fE["Mesh/z"]]
.
.
.
.
        self.powerflux = 300
.
.

xp = surface(fExp,fHxp,"p")
xp.start()
.
.
xp.join()

print "wg.power =", xp.powerflux
```

---

```
python ****.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "postprocess_3D_thread2.py", line 132, in <module>
    print "xp.power =", xp.powerflux
AttributeError: 'surface' object has no attribute 'powerflux'
```

I am attempting to run the class method run() under multiprocessing It runs just fine and  the run() method multiprocesses but I cannot figure out how to get out self.powerflux out of the run() method into my class attributes! Could someone kindly tell me how multiprocessing is done within class methods? I've been looking for weeks and I'm really stumped and cannot find this on Google.
Thanks so much,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from multiple processes can be awkward -- here's one way to do it from [the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

### source

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def calc(a, b, resultval):
    resultval.value = a+b

def main():
    num = mp.Value('d', 0.0)

    p = mp.Process(target=calc, args=(1, 2, num))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### output

```
3.0
```